# Azure Machine Learning Studio, Python script input format

Tags: python, csv, azure-machine-learning-service

I am execute a python script in Azure ML studio. The python script will take a single string input, process the string and then return the processed result.

I am using "Enter Data Manually" as input(connect to "Dataset1" on "Execute Python Script" module), and the input format is CSV. This input is also my "Web Service Input". So, in the python script, I will get the input text like following,

```
         input_text = dataframe1.iat[0, 0]
```

But, I found that I have to enter the text start from the 2nd row, like the follow picture.

[image]

If I put the text in the first row, then the python script won't execute. From the error message, seems its' index out of bound error. But I did put data at the first row and first column, the only column. Why I still get this error? I am not very clear on the input scheme. Can someone explain? Thanks.

```
[Error]         Caught exception while executing function: Traceback (most recent call last):
[Error]           File "C:\server\invokepy.py", line 199, in batch
[Error]             odfs = mod.azureml_main(*idfs)
[Error]           File "C:\temp\b792c87679e1424fb3300c65b0231c07.py", line 43, in azureml_main
[Error]             input_text = dataframe1.iat[0, 0]
[Error]           File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1610, in __getitem__
[Error]             return self.obj.get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
[Information]         theano/typed_list/type.py                      2016-09-06 14:31:24         3870
[Information]         theano/typed_list/type.pyc                     2016-09-06 14:31:26         6025
[Information]         theano/typed_list/__init__.py                  2016-09-06 14:31:24           71
[Information]         theano/typed_list/__init__.pyc                 2016-09-06 14:31:26          287
[Information]         theano/updates.py                              2016-09-06 14:31:24         3405
[Information]         theano/updates.pyc                             2016-09-06 14:31:26         3317
[Information]         theano/version.py                              2016-09-06 14:31:24          208
[Information]         theano/version.pyc                             2016-09-06 14:31:26          380
[Information]         theano/__init__.py                             2016-09-06 14:31:24         6675
[Information]         theano/__init__.pyc                            2016-09-06 14:31:26         6689
[Information]         [ READING ] 0:00:00
[Information]         Input pandas.DataFrame #1:
[Information]         Empty DataFrame
[Information]         Columns: [Text start from here.]
[Information]         Index: []
[Error]           File "C:\pyhome\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1832, in get_value
[Error]             return _maybe_box_datetimelike(series._values[index])
[Error]         IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
[Error]         Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

Comment: I'm wondering if the "HasHeader" being checked is causing this. In the error, it looks like the text may be interpreted incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Jon, you are right about the "HasHeader" checkbox. If I remove the check from the checkbox, I can start to enter data from the first row, and the experiment runs properly. Only funny thing is, when I deployed it to a web service, the request body structure changed. The column name changed from "Column 0" to "Col1". Although it works fine in both scenario, but the input scheme is really not that straightforward.